# Extjs scrollable panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a panel where I insert some HTML from the server:

```
myPanel.update(response.responseText);
```

But if this text is too big, none of the scrollbars appear to navigate the text.

How can I configure a vertical scrollbar in this panel?

This is my panel definition:

```
{
  xtype:'panel',
  width: '100%',
  height: 300,
  id:'mypanel'
},
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Basically you would just add the **[autoScroll](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-autoScroll)** property like

```
autoScroll: true
```

Here's a working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/czrt6/3/)**

Comment: This not work for me. I had just update this question with my panel definition. thanks.

Comment: @paulo First: Your `width` is invalid cause it has to be a number. Second: see this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/czrt6/3/)

Answer (score 10):

...or if you always want a [vertical scrollbar](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-overflowY)

```
overflowY: 'scroll'
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually you should have two properties together:

```
autoScroll: 'true'
```

and

```
height: 300
```

They work together, one without the other will not produce the scroll bar.